# Delete two records from one table

Tags: sql

```
Delete from patient WHERE patientId='011' AND '022'
```

Can the above sql statement delete two records from one table?

Comment: Your delete statement isn't correct & short answer is "NO".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
Delete from patient WHERE patientId='011' OR patientId = '022'

-- alternatively IN
Delete from patient WHERE patientId IN ('011', '022')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use In here:

```
Delete from patient WHERE patientId In ('011', '022')
```